# Did 'mv *' and now I can't find my files

Tags: debian, mv

All in the title.

I did `mv *` or `mv *.mkv` (I don't remember) and now I can't find my files.

Can I get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities here depending on what was in your current directory when you ran the command.  But before that I want to cover what the asterisk does.

### * (globbing)

In bash (and, to my knowledge, other shells), an asterisk performs a type of filename expansion called [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

This basically expands the argument into a number of arguments that match the expression.  So if you have just a `*` you get all of the (non-hidden) files in the current directory as an argument.  For `*.mkv` it would expand to the list of all files ending with the extension `.mkv`.

### mv * (with two files)

The mv command requires multiple arguments, and is generally used with two, moving the file at the path denotes by the first argument (the source) to the path denoted by the second argument (the destination).  Generally speaking, this will replace the a file at the destination if it is present with the source file.  In this case, recovering the original destination file might still be possible but would require file recovery techniques (i.e. the same as if you had deleted the file with `rm`).

So if you only had two files in your directory (or two mkv files if you ran that command), you would have effectively removed one of the files.

However, given that it sounds like you cannot find the files at all I think something else happened.

### mv * (with many files)

If you had more than two matching files in the directory, `mv` would attempt to move all of them into a directory denoted by the final argument.

From a test I just did, it looks like it will error out if the last path does not denote a directory and simply do nothing.

Given this, I think your files are probably fine and simply got moved into one of the sub-directories where your files were.  I'm not 100% sure but I would assume it would be the last one alphabetically.

For example, if your directory looked like this (subdir is a directory while file*.mkv are files):

```
$ ls
subdir  file1.mkv  file2.mkv  file3.mkv
```

And you ran `mv *`.  I would expect you now see:

```
$ ls
subdir
```

In this case, your file are probably in subdir:

```
$ ls subdir/
file1.mkv  file2.mkv  file3.mkv
```

If you can't find *any* of the files, even looking in sub-directories, you may need to provide more context for what you were doing in order to fully figure out what happened.  You might also want to search through your bash history (`~/.bash_history`) to see exactly what commands you ran.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Your third hypothesis was right and I could recover my files.